# Drupal ignores my table definition when installing a module

Tags: 7, hooks, database

What am I doing wrong? This is what I have in commerce_xpay.install.

```
function commerce_xpay_schema() {
    $schema = array();

    $schema['commerce_xpay_ipn'] = array(
            'description' => 'Stores processed IPNs.',
            'fields' => array(
                    'ipn_id' => array(
                            'description' => 'Serial numeric ID of the IPN in the local database.',
                            'type' => 'serial',
                            'unsigned' => TRUE,
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                    ),
                    'transaction_id' => array(
                            'description' => 'The X-Pay transaction ID.',
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'length' => 255,
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => '',
                    ),
                    'terminal_id' => array(
                            'description' => 'The X-Pay terminal id',
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'length' => 255,
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => '',
                    ),
                    'response' => array(
                            'description' => 'The response of the server',
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'length' => 255,
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => '',
                    ),
                    'payer_email' => array(
                            'description' => 'The e-mail of the payer.',
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'length' => 255,
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => '',
                    ),
                    'transaction_date' => array(
                            'description' => 'The date of the transaction.',
                            'type' => 'date',
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                    ),
                    'card_type' => array(
                            'description' => 'The type of the card used in the transaction.',
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'length' => 255,
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => '',
                    ),
                    'amount' => array(
                            'description' => 'The amount of the transaction.',
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'length' => 255,
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => '',
                    ),
                    'transaction_type' => array(
                            'description' => 'The type of the transaction.',
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'length' => 255,
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => '',
                    ),
                    'mac' => array(
                            'description' => 'The amount of the transaction.',
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'length' => 255,
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => '',
                    ),
                    'currency' => array(
                            'description' => 'The currency used for the transaction.',
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'length' => 255,
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => '',
                    ),
                    'order_id' => array(
                            'description' => 'The order ID the payment belongs to.',
                            'type' => 'int',
                            'unsigned' => TRUE,
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => 0,
                    ),
                    'txn_id' => array(
                            'description' => 'The payment transaction ID the payment belongs to.',
                            'type' => 'int',
                            'unsigned' => TRUE,
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => 0,
                    ),
                    'created' => array(
                            'description' => 'The Unix timestamp when the IPN was received.',
                            'type' => 'int',
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => 0,
                    ),
                    'changed' => array(
                            'description' => 'The Unix timestamp when the IPN was last updated.',
                            'type' => 'int',
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => 0,
                    ),
                    'test_ipn' => array(
                            'description' => 'Boolean indicating whether or not this was a test IPN sent by the Sandbox.',
                            'type' => 'int',
                            'size' => 'tiny',
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => 0,
                    ),
            ),
            'primary key' => array('ipn_id'),
            'foreign keys' => array(
                    'order_id' => array(
                            'table' => 'commerce_order',
                            'columns'=> array('order_id' => 'order_id'),
                    ),
                    'txn_id' => array(
                            'table' => 'commerce_payment_transaction',
                            'columns'=> array('payment_id' => 'payment_id'),
                    ),
            ),
            'indexes' => array(
                    'transaction_id' => array('transaction_id'),
            ),
    );

    return $schema;
}
```

Comment: Do you completely disable *and* uninstall the module between your attempts? Your schema definition will not be called again once your module has been installed.

Comment: @marcvangend i simply disable the module withouth uninstalling it, so this might be the issue. Since i'm developing a custom module, to simulate an install i need to package the module and install it through the interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing an error message, but at first glance I'd guess it's because of the `transaction_date` column.

`date` is not a valid data type in Drupal 7 (see [Data Types](http://drupal.org/node/159605)). You can either use an `int` column and store a UNIX timestamp, or use the `mysql_type` property instead of `type`, and set that `datetime`.

Comment: This is true, there is no error message but that is because i wasn't uninstalling the module before re-installing it i'm afraid

Comment: Ah ok! I'd advise installing the Devel module...then you can go to http://mysite.com/devel/reinstall and get your module re-installed automatically

Comment: Perfect, everything works correctly.